# How can I parse a data from website chart using IMPORTXML?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to extract data from a website using IMPORT XML and the answer is "Imported Xml content can not be parsed.". Appreciate any help:

=IMPORTXML("https://www.infomoney.com.br/cotacoes/b3/fii/fundos-imobiliarios-gcff11/","//*[@id='dividend_graph_wrapper']")

Explored the page code to find other options to get the data from the chart[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPcG9.png)